# JMESPath expression to flatten array of objects, each with nested arrays of objects

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath

I have JSON containing an array of databases, each database has an array of users, e.g.

```json
{"databases": [
  {"db": "db_a", "users": [{"name": "alice"}, {"name": "alex"}]},
  {"db": "db_b", "users": [{"name": "bob"}, {"name": "brienne"}]}
]}
```

I would like to produce a flat array of databases and users, i.e.

```json
[
  {"db": "db_a", "name": "alice"},
  {"db": "db_a", "name": "alex"},
  {"db": "db_b", "name": "bob"},
  {"db": "db_b", "name": "brienne"}
]
```

In SQL terms this would be a cartesian join or cartesian product, but I'm not sure of the correct term in a tree structure. The closest I've got so far is

```
databases[].users[]
```

which produces

```json
[{"name": "alice"}, {"name": "alex"}, {"name": "bob"}, {"name": "brienne"}]
```

and

```
databases[].{db: db, name: users[].name}
```

which produces

```json
[
  {"db": "db_a", "name": ["alice", "alex"]},
  {"db": "db_b", "name": ["bob", "brienne"]}
]
```

Addendum: I'm happy to accept "You can't do that with JMESPath, here's why ..." as an answer. An [HN Comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16402080)`` hints at this

> can't reference parents when doing iteration. Why? All options for iteration, [* ] and map, all use the iterated item as the context for any expression. There's no opportunity to get any other values in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of JEP 18 you can use a [let expression](https://jmespath.site/main/#spec-let-expressions), available in `jmespath-community` on PyPI.

> A let-expression introduces lexical scoping and lets you bind variables that are evaluated In the context of a given lexical scope. This enables queries that can refer to elements defined outside of their current element

```
databases[*].let $db = db in users[*].{"db": $db, "name": name}
```

This produces

```json
[
  [
    {"db": "db_a", "name": "alice"},
    {"db": "db_a", "name": "alex"}
  ],
  [
    {"db": "db_b", "name": "bob"},
    {"db": "db_b", "name": "brienne"}
  ]
]
```

As pointed out by Alex Willmer, you can flatten this with

```
(databases[*].let $db = db in users[(].{"db": $db, "name": name})[]
```

producing

```json
[
  { "db": "db_a", "name": "alice" },
  { "db": "db_a", "name": "alex" },
  { "db": "db_b", "name": "bob" },
  { "db": "db_b", "name": "brienne" }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with *just* JMESPath, because JMESPath expressions can only refer to a single scope. There's no way to reach the outer scope (database objects), when the current scope is a user object. [JEP 11](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.site/pull/6) would allow access to other scopes, but it hasn't been accepted after several years.

On Ansible it can be done with other filters (h/t Vladimir), and some ugliness

```
databases_users: "{{ 
    databases | subelements('users')
              | to_json | from_json
              | json_query('[*].{db: [0].db, name: [1].name}')
}}"
```

### Explanation

As a reminder, our starting point is

```
[ {"db": "db_a", "users": [{"name": "alice"}, {"name": "alex"}]},
  ...]
```

the `subelements` filter transforms this into a list of Python tuple pairs

```
[ ({"db": "db_a", "users": [{"name": "alice"}, {"name": "alex"}]},
   {"name": "alice"}),
  ...]
```

`to_json` and `from_json` convert the tuple pairs to lists (JMESPath for Python ignores tuples)

```
[ [{"db": "db_a", "users": [{"name": "alice"}, {"name": "alex"}]},
   {"name": "alice"}],
  ...]
```

`json_query` selects the desired `db` and `user` values

```
[ {"db": "db_a", "name": "alice"},
  ...]
```

Comment: A jq filter can do it: `.databases | map({db, name: .users[].name})` ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5YHjzcspb5)).

Comment: This is no longer the case with the adoption of [JEP 18](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.jep/pull/18)

Comment: Sweet, happy to accept a written up answer

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's an option but a custom function can do it like so:

```
import json
import jmespath


class CustomFunctions(jmespath.functions.Functions):
    @jmespath.functions.signature({'types': ['object']}, {'types': ['array']})
    def _func_map_merge(self, obj, arg):
        result = []
        for element in arg:
            merged_object = super()._func_merge(obj, element)
            result.append(merged_object)
        return result


options = jmespath.Options(custom_functions=CustomFunctions())


source = """
{"databases": [
  {"db": "db_a", "users": [{"name": "alice"}, {"name": "alex"}]},
  {"db": "db_b", "users": [{"name": "bob"}, {"name": "brienne"}]}
]}

"""

jmespath_expr = """
    databases[].map_merge({"db": db}, @.users[])[]
"""

result = jmespath.search(jmespath_expr, json.loads(source), options=options)
result
```

Producing

```
[{'db': 'db_a', 'name': 'alice'},
 {'db': 'db_a', 'name': 'alex'},
 {'db': 'db_b', 'name': 'bob'},
 {'db': 'db_b', 'name': 'brienne'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to [loop subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html)

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_db: "{{ my_db + [ item.0|combine(item.1) ] }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('subelements',databases,'users') }}"
```

Comment: Would you prefer I edit/expand your answer, then accept it? Or submit my own answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.